# Weird things going on with my Drag n' Drop Inventory System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A video showcasing the problem: `https://clipchamp.com/watch/73zJjlfc2X4`

Hi there fellow Internet People,

I stumbled upon a weird problem going on with my Drag n' Drop Inventory System, where it sometimes, not always, picks up a second object that the one the cursor is hovering over. All the related scripts are linked below.

The MouseFollower, which is constantly following the cursor and acts as a parent the object can use, and only one at a time. The code is "MouseFollower".: `https://pastebin.com/HQ5FHwW4`

The ItemScript, which is the script that every item in the inventory UI has, which are the weird long blocks. The code is "ItemScript".: `https://pastebin.com/iH0kBDNc`

There is also an InventoryManager which the canvas has, but it is currently only managing whenever you open and close the inventory and nothing else.

I tried to add the small red box called "MouseVisualizer" that gives an idea of where the current position of the MouseFollower is, to see if the problem was something with it's position being somewhere else, but no. You can also see some of the Hierarchy at the very end of the video if that helps. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very simple inventory using your code and i realized when you hover over an item cursorHasEntered is set to true , now there is nothing wrong with that but when the mouse exit cursorHasEntered  is still set to true

you should do this instead , its the same code but we added IPointerExitHandler which detects when our pointer leaves the item

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ItemScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler , IPointerExitHandler
{
    private bool CursorHasEntered = false;
    private bool CanBeDropped = false;
    public static bool MouseBusy = false;

    public GameObject mousefollower;
    public GameObject items;

    //Detect if the Cursor starts to pass over the GameObject
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        CursorHasEntered = true;
        Debug.Log("Mouse Entered");
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        CursorHasEntered = false;
        Debug.Log("Bye");
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) == true && CursorHasEntered == true && MouseBusy == false)
        {
            CanBeDropped = true;
            transform.SetParent(mousefollower.transform);
            MouseBusy = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) == false && CanBeDropped == true)
        {
            CursorHasEntered = false;
            CanBeDropped = false;
            StartCoroutine(NewParent());
            MouseBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator NewParent()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        transform.SetParent(items.transform);
    }


}
```

Comment: Instead of `Input.GetKey` you probably want to handle those **once** and rather use `Input.GetKeyDown` and `Input.GetKeyUp`

Comment: I removed the IPointerExitHandler to begin with because it would just drop it whenever the cursor moved because of the 'drag' effect it almost has. I gave it a try again, and by messing around with it's collider, I made it work good enough. Thank you for your help and time.